# Updating Value of Input to user's Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to update a page by echoing the input of a user in real time through ajax. However, when a user types in something and clicks 'send' there is nothing echoed. But when I preset the input to a random word through html and click 'send' the word is shown. Why is this and how can I update the input value without manually doing so in html?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="userName" name="typeit" value=""/>
<!-- Input containing preset value -->
<input type="text" id="userName" name="typeit" value="cindy"/>
<input type="button" id="text_value" value="send"/>
```

**JQuery**

```
// I used this to check if the actual input was being updated 
$('#text_value').click(function() {
var text_value = $("#userName").val();
if(text_value=='') {
alert("Please enter a title first");
}else{
alert(text_value);
}
});
```

Comment: you want to update the value without hitting "send"?

Comment: And where's the ajax ?

Comment: Why do you have two inputs with same id and name? IDs should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a keyboard event like `keyup`:

```
$('#userName').keyup(function() {
    var text_value = $(this).val();
    if(text_value=='') {
      alert("Please enter a title first");
    }else{
      $("p").html(text_value);
    }
});
```

Also `id` can only be used once on the page so you need to change one of them:

```
<input type="text" id="userName" name="typeit" value=""/>
<!-- Input containing preset value -->
<input type="text" id="somethingElse" name="typeit" value="cindy"/>
<input type="button" id="text_value" value="send"/>

<!--for my example-->
<p>Update</p>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ufm2m1xu/)

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your HTML as you define `id="userName"` twice. If you compare strings you always need the `===` identical operator. Try out this snippet:

```js
// I used this to check if the actual input was being updated
$('#text_value').click(function() {
  var text_value = $("#userName").val();
  if (text_value === '')
    alert("Please enter a title first");
  else
    alert(text_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Uname" name="typeit" value="" />
<!-- Input containing preset value -->
<input type="text" id="userName" name="typeit" value="cindy" />
<input type="button" id="text_value" value="send" />

<div id="test"></div>
```